# Why do I get a "invalid pointer" error when trying to install the gdalUtils package (in R)?

Tags: r, linux, gdal, rgdal

I am trying to install the gdalUtils package on my Linux system (Parrot OS, Debian-based). However, whenever I try this, I get the following error: `munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer`. What is going wrong? As far as I know, I am not missing any GDAL binaries.

Comment: Building from source or installing a .deb? I guess I'm just asking, what are your typing in your terminal when you `try this`?

Comment: I get a similar error when trying to install gdalUtils and rgdal from Rstudio (version 1.2.5042) in ubuntu 20.04

Comment: An extensive discussion, in the context of `sf` [edzer-rspatial](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/844) which gives us a kind of check list of things to evaluate in our systems as we try to get `ubuntu 20.04`, `gdal` and friends working with `R`, `4.0.0` in my case. I mainly have to remove many scattered instances of prior installs of `geos` and `proj` that interfere either during compilation or at runtime. HTH